# How to create separate methods to create SKLabelNode or SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

i've been looking at a few Sprite kit tutorials today and I can't seem to find any that are similar so i've came to stackoverflow to understand the basics of Sprite Kit.

I know to create text the code is:

```
SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontName:@"Chalkduster"];

label.text = @"This is a string which is displayed in an SKView";
label.fontSize = 30;
label.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);

[self addChild:label];
```

I know this adds a string into the SKView but what in wondering is how do I create it in places other than:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
     //above code here
}
return self;
}
```

i've tried a simple method like:

```
-(void)exampleText{
    //SKLabelNode code here
}
```

but they don't seem to work maybe its something to do return value(If someone could link me to a tutorial which could help me understand return better that would be great)

The same goes for SKSpriteNode:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png"

sprite.name = "Sprite";
sprite.scale = 0.5;

[self addChild:sprite];
```

This was also entered in the `initWithSize:` method

Is there any possible way to create them in other methods? **As well as SKAction Types** ( If thats what you call them) (Of course there is)

Also i'm curious how I can use if statements to affect nodes such as this code:

```
if (sprite.alpha == 0 || sprite.alpha < 0){
     [sprite removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: did you actually call the exampleText method? Verify that with a breakpoint and single-stepping through code.

Comment: yes it works but i want to know how i can create them in separate methods then call them elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer!

To create `SKLabelNode` and `SKSpriteNode` in separate methods you create a method like below:

```
-(SKNode*)makeSprite{
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png";

    sprite.name = @"sprite";
    sprite.scale = 0.5;
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
}
```

then you create another method like below:

```
-(void)createSprite{
    SKNode *sprite[self makeSprite];

    [self addChild:sprite];
}
```

and then you add the `createSprite` method to:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
         [self createSprite];
}
return self;
}
```